# How to remove Click handler for checkboxes bound to bool[] array

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Data context class:

```
class ImageHandler : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    bool[] directions = new bool[8];

    public bool[] Directions { get { return directions; } }

    // ...
}
```

XAML:

```
<UniformGrid Columns="8">
    <CheckBox Content=" N" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Directions[0]}" Click="CheckBox_Click"/>
    <CheckBox Content="NW" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Directions[1]}" Click="CheckBox_Click"/>
    <CheckBox Content=" W" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Directions[2]}" Click="CheckBox_Click"/>
    <!-- ... -->
</UniformGrid>
```

Code behind:

```
private void CheckBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     imageHandler.UpdateImage();
}
```

So, I have boolean array in the data context class, and 8 checkboxes, bound to each array member. Click event handler recalculates the image, according to new `directions` array state. How can I change this code to remove `CheckBox_Click` event handler, making this working according to MVVM pattern? I need a way to detect a change made in `directions` array, without writing event handler.

Comment: Do you want to handle the click on checkbox in your viewmodel? Then WPF checkbox has Command property you can bind that to ICommand in your view model (using RelayCommand) and also pass parameter to see which check box (in your case bound item) was updated.

Comment: My another suggestion would be to also change the XAML, if you are sure that your viewmodel will decide what shows in your UniformGrid i.e. if it is always presenting data from viewmodel then you can also define ItemsControl in your UniformGrid and then define a template for ItemTemplate so that way you will also not need to bind your checkboxes with defined index in XAML and not maintain it later

Comment: @bjoshi - implementing ICommand is OK for me, post this command as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then WPF checkbox has Command property you can bind that to ICommand in your view model (using RelayCommand) and also pass parameter to see which check box (in your case bound item) was updated.

My another suggestion would be to also change the XAML, if you are sure that your viewmodel will decide what shows in your UniformGrid i.e. if it is always presenting data from viewmodel then you can also define ItemsControl in your UniformGrid and then define a template for ItemTemplate so that way you will also not need to bind your checkboxes with defined index in XAML and not maintain it later

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an `ItemsControl` for this. It removes the need to add your UI elements manually one by one in XAML and also removes the need for event handlers.

ViewModel:

```
class ImageHandler : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    List<Direction> directions = new List<Direction>();
    public List<Direction> Directions { get { return directions; } }
    // ...

    public ImageHandler()
    {
       Directions.Add(new Direction {DisplayName = " N" });
       Directions.Add(new Direction {DisplayName = "NW" });
       Directions.Add(new Direction {DisplayName = " W" });
       //.. Etc

       Directions.ForEach(x => x.OnIsSelectedChanged = OnDirectionSelectionChanged);
    }

    private void OnDirectionSelectionChanged(Direction direction)
    {
       //.. Your logic here
    }
}
```

Data Item:

```
public class Direction: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private bool _isSelected;
   public bool IsSelected
   {
       get { return _isSelected; }
       set
       {
           _isSelected = value;
           if (OnIsSelectedChanged != null)
               OnIsSelectedChanged(this);

           NotifyPropertyChange(() => IsSelected);
       }
   }

   public string DisplayName {get;set;}

   public Action<Direction> OnIsSelectedChanged {get;set;}
}
```

XAML:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Directions}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <UniformGrid Columns="8"/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>      
   </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <CheckBox Content="{Binding DisplayName}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
       </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

**Side note**: MVVM is not about no-code behind, nor removing event handlers. It is about putting UI where UI belongs, and Data where Data belongs, and an intermediary layer (the ViewModel) in between these two. Therefore, your current event-based approach does not break MVVM, as long as you keep the logic in the ViewModel (by delegating like `ViewModel.DoSomething()` in the event handlers.)